# Does Laravel pagination loads the whole page when paginating? I am using inertiajs

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-pagination

For me it seems that when I call Laravel pagination `next`*`page`*`url`, the whole page is loaded from backend, not only the needed data (for a table for example). Is that right?

If so, how can I distract the needed data from the whole page response? What I mean "needed data" is -for example - the journals variable from the below controller method:

```
return Inertia::render("Journal/Index", [
    "journals" => Journal::filter($this->getFilters())
        ->paginate(10)
        ->onEachSide(1)
        ->withQueryString(),
 ]);
```

Every help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Inertia's Link component instead of traditional anchor tags?

Comment: I am using axios. It is a quasar table.

Comment: I believe that's the problem then... Quasar components doesn't know how to make Inertia requests. You can disable the pagination links on the Table component and render them manually using the Link component from Inertia.